# ActiveJob with Resque plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, rails-activejob

Is there a way to use Resque plugins, such as [resque-loner](https://github.com/resque/resque-loner), with ActiveJob and Resque as backend for it?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, all you'll have to do is add `include Resque::Plugins::UniqueJob` to the job in your `app/jobs` folder. Is that not working?